# Canvas - get pixel colour - what am I missing?

Tags: image, html5-canvas

Using this code as base http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/158/index.html

I code the following:

```
    $canvas = $('<canvas/>');
    ctx = $canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    var image = new Image(); // create an image object in memory
    image.onload = function () {
      // render the image on the canvas
      $canvas.width(this.width).height(this.height); // resize the canvas
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height); 
      var nav =  $("#navigation"); // get the navigation container
      // find a pixel about in the middle where the navigation would be
      var pos = {
        left: nav.position().left+(nav.width()/2), 
        top: nav.position().top+(nav.height()/2) 
      }
      var pixel = ctx.getImageData(pos.left,pos.top, 1, 1).data;
      canvas=null; // no longer need this canvas 
      // invert the pixel colour, ignoring the alpha channel
      var invertedPixelColor = "rgba("+(255-pixel[0])+", "+
                                       (255-pixel[1])+", "+
                                       (255-pixel[2])+", "+
                                       1+")"; 
      nav.css("color",invertedPixelColor); // set the nav text to inverted color
    }
    image.src = imageURL; // load the image, triggering the calc
```

[Running example](http://plungjan.name/test/detectbackground.html)

I have the following issues with the example:

1. why does the image not render correctly to the canvas? (scroll down in the demo to see the canvas rendered)
2. why do I only get 0s back from the image data?

I have

```
window.console && 
   console.log("before: rgba("+pixel[0]+", "+pixel[1]+", "+pixel[2]+", "+pixel[3]+")");
window.console && 
   console.log("after: rgba("+(255-pixel[0])+", "+(255-pixel[1])+", "+(255-pixel[2])+", "+1+")");
```

and it returns

```
before: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 
after: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
```

I hope I am missing something simple

**UPDATE** I was - it seems that `$("<canvas/>)[0].getContext('2d');` is not 100% happy context...

Comment: Why is this voted down after 4 years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On you 2 questions.

(1). Use just use 3 arguments when calling ctx.drawImage

```
ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
```

(2). The jquery $canvas object you're creating doesn't appear to be an html canvas element.

So you're jquery element creation needs fixin' or just use the old fashioned document.createElement.

```
canvas=document.createElement("canvas");
```

Those couple of tweaks an you're good to go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing setting text colour depending on background</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ctx;   
$(function(){ // on page load, this should likely be on image transition
    $(".nav").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var imageURL = $(this).data("img");
        $("#content").css("background","url("+imageURL+")");
        // creating canvas object in memory. 
        // Since I do not append it anywhere it is not rendered
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var image = new Image(); // create an image object in memory
        image.onload = function () {

          // render the image on the canvas
          canvas.width=this.width;
          canvas.height=this.height; // resize the canvas
          ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0); 
          var nav =  $("#navigation"); // get the navigation container
          // find a pixel about in the middle where the navigation would be
          var pos = {left: nav.position().left+(nav.width()/2), top: nav.position().top+(nav.height()/2) }
          var pixel = ctx.getImageData(pos.left,pos.top, 1, 1).data;
          canvas=null; // no longer need this canvas 

          var invertedPixelColor = "rgba("+(255-pixel[0])+", "+(255-pixel[1])+", "+(255-pixel[2])+", "+1+")"; // invert it, ignoring the alpha channel
          nav.css("color",invertedPixelColor); // set the nav text to inverted color
          // here you could save the colour and reuse it 
          // if the user navigates to the same image
        }
        image.src = imageURL; // load the image, triggering the calc
    });
});
</script>
<style>
#navigation { text-align:center }
#content { width:640px; height:480px; background: url(city-q-c-640-480-6.jpg) }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="navigation">This text should have different color depending on background<br/>
        <a href="#" class="nav" data-img="city-q-c-640-480-5.jpg">City 1</a> | <a href="#" class="nav" data-img="city-q-c-640-480-6.jpg">City 2</a> | <a href="#" class="nav" data-img="city-q-c-640-480-2.jpg">City 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That sounded promising, but nothing new - the canvas is smaller than the image, the imageData does not return any colours I updated [my page](http://plungjan.name/test/detectbackground.html) - also if it hadn't been a canvas object, how would I get any imageData at all and no errors on ctx access?

Comment: Works fine for me :)  Check out this fiddle that you'll have to view with Chrome of Mozilla because IE is cranky about CORS--but code should work fine on your own site as CORS is not in effect then: http://jsfiddle.net/f6Gbp/1/   (Your canvas is the same size as your image and the pixels are correctly sampled and inverted.)

Comment: AH - I DID have to resize. And amazingly enough you have a CORS image site, I tried a fiddle with lorempixel which failed in Chrome and Fx because of the cors issue...